# ReSharper To-Do Explorer regex pattern for [Obsolete]

Tags: regex, resharper

I would like to have To-do Explorer Items for my [Obsolete] marked sources.

I started with the default Todo regex and tried a few things. Currently I have this Regex:

```
(\W)Obsolete(.*)
```

which shows me only this in Explorer

```
Obsolete
```

when the source is:

```
[Obsolete("Use something instead")]
internal const string magicString = "uglystyle";
```

I would like to have something like this to be shown:

```
Obsolete("Use something instead")
```

An online regextester shows me the full line for the given regex. Even the VS2012 Quick-Search with Expression marks the whole entry. What am I missing?

Comment: Currently i think that Resharper is cutting the result down to the identifier. If i use the same regex for "in string" to, the whole string is shown. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper matches these regular expressions against nodes in the syntax tree, rather than the plain document text. When matching against comments, that's the whole string value of (usually) the line, so the captured value includes the text after the tag (incidentally, you can use a capture group called "TAG" to cause the keyword to be shown in bold in the todo explorer).

But this means, when matching against identifiers (e.g. variable names, or class names in usage or declarations), it only matches the actual identifier, and not the surrounding text.

This is shame, as a tag based on the `Obsolete` attribute is a really nice idea.